# How do i look up a folder i know only the start of?

Tags: android, filesystems

I am looking for the camera folder on different Android devices,

It is variously called `100ANDRO`, `100MEDIA`, `100lgdsc`, and `Camera` on different devices.

There may be other versions of this folder, but there seems to be a pattern; if it's not called Camera, it begins with "100".

How do I lookup folders that begin with 100?

Comment: FYI you need to handle numbers other than "100" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system#Directory_and_file_structure for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `java.io.FileNameFilter`. It works nicely with `File.listFiles(FileNameFilter)` as you can see in this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_listfiles_filename_filter.htm)

For your problem, you can use this `FileNameFilter` (**Updated**: @Andrew pointed out the directory name structure for DCIM folders)

```
FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (pattern.matches(name) || name.equalsIgnoreCase("Camera"));
    }
};
```

and for the `pattern`:

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z0-9]{5}");
```